# how does google create the png image animation currently on its homepage

Tags: animation, png, base64

how does google create  the png image animation currently on its homepage, seems to be png encoded base64 files.

How do the png animations run without javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a link to the actual image. The google front page changes depending on region. For me it's just the normal google logo at the moment.

Comment: yes me too now, it was an Olympic flame that was about 10 png images encoded with base64. It also worked wtih JS off, which was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It can be [CSS Sprite Sheet Animations](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps) or JavaScript-based animation. APNG is not supported in Google Chrome.